# Can I use already used variable names in callbacks?

Tags: javascript, callback, closures

I have code like this (using node_redis):

```
client.sismember(someRecord, someArray, function(err, res) {
    if(res) { /* some code */ }
    else {
        client.sismember(otherRecord, otherArray, function(err, res) {
            /* some code */
        }
    }
}
```

Should I rename the arguments of a second callback function or will it work correctly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to use different variable names *unless* you intend for the inner function to refer to the variables of the outer function. As to whether you "should" rename them, if the functions are really short like that it would be fairly clear which is which, but if "some code" is really long it might be clearer if they used different names.

Answer (score 2):

It will work correctly; the variables in the inner function will shadow the variables from the outer function.

You might want to rename the variables anyway. That makes it easier to see what's used where, and it allows you to use the variables from the outer function in the inner function if you need them.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah you can, thats totally valid because or their scope but would be better if the name differs so that they in the near  future dont confuse you